# How to check runnung apps on iOS device using shell script on Mac

Tags: ios, macos, shell

I want to get list of the currently running apps on my iOS device, connected to the Mac. Is there a way to do that through shell ?

Comment: Were you able to do this?

Comment: I think, i did not manage to do it. My idea was that i wanted to know, when the app will finish, so i wanted to check periodically if the app is in the running apps. I was sending data over http anyways, so I just sent exit request when my app was exiting to a local server on the mac (this was only in the testing build of the app). It is kind of a stupid hack, but it worked.

Comment: I see, so you weren't able to get a list of processes... Thank you for taking the time if replying me.